# Open a docx file as a zip in vim

Tags: vim, zip, docx

I've got a `docx` file, which is really just a `zip` but since the extension isn't `.zip`, vim fails to recognize that, and opens the raw data.

I've tried opening the file and setting the filetype to zip, `:set filetype=zip`, I've tried opening the file as a directory, `:e path/to/file.docx/` and I've tried opening the file

Is there any way that I can force vim to open the docx as a zip?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Naturally, within seconds of asking I do a `:help zip` and find the `pi_zip` plugin which explicitly tells me:

```
   Apparently there are a number of archivers which generate zip files that
   don't use the .zip extension (.jar, .xpi, etc).  To handle such files,
   place a line in your <.vimrc> file: >

    au BufReadCmd *.jar,*.xpi call zip#Browse(expand("<amatch>"))

   One can simply extend this line to accommodate additional extensions that
   should be treated as zip files.
```

Which I can use to add the filetype to that list, and then also showed me

```
 au BufReadCmd *.docx call zip#Browse(expand("<amatch>"))
```

or alternatively

```
 call zip#Browse(expand("/path/to/file"))
```

which I can use explicitly if I don't want to always open a docx like that.

If error on writing: check file permission, maybe it `root:root`.

Comment: Is there a command-line option, so that we don't have to customize a vimrc file?

Comment: Thanks, TankorSmash.  I was hoping that it might be something short like `:e ++ff=dos` to have vim recognize that the current file is in DOS format.  But a long command is still helpful.  I also found that vim automatically recognizes `*.xlsx` files as zip archives, but not `*.xls` files.  The latter might not be vim's fault.  Even `unzip -l *.xls` yields some funny results.

Comment: But such solution do not allow saving?

Answer (score 0):

I just started to use https://github.com/lbrayner/vim-rzip, which also provides support for browsing zip-format files recursively, meaning if you have a zip inside the zip it also opens and you can navigate further down the tree.

You can define any file extension in the .vimrc, like this:

```
echo "let g:rzipPlugin_extra_ext = '*.jar,*.war,*.ear'" >> ~/.vimrc
```